# Can we call a class name in test class of a controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

Can any one let me know.Can we call a class name in a test class of a controller.When i run the test class of the controller it shows as 0% and the apex class as 60%.

For example :Say i have a controller named as edit page ,apex class as TestData and now in the test class of an edit page the apex class name testate is used.Any suggestion please.

Test Class :

```
@isTest
public class EditpageOverridecontrollerTest{
    public static TestMethod void TestEditpageOverridecontroller(){
        List<Profile> profileList = [SELECT Id FROM Profile where Name = 'Community Subscription Administrator' Limit 1];
        if(profileList != null && profileList.size() > 0){


            Account acc = TestDataGenerator.createAccount('Edbaccount','Commercial','Basic' );
            insert acc;

            Contact con = TestDataGenerator.createContact('joyTest',acc, 'test@gmail.com');
            insert con;

            User usr1 = TestDataGenerator.createNewUser (con,'test1', 'atest1','test1@gmail.com','edb1@demo.com','atest1',profileList[0],'America/Los_Angeles','en_US','UTF-8','en_US');
            insert usr1;


            List<case> caseList = new List<Case>();
            Case cs = TestDataGenerator.createCase(con, 'New');
            caseList.add(cs);
            Case cs1 = TestDataGenerator.createCase(con,'Solution Suggested');
            caseList.add(cs1);

            insert caseList;

            Case newCase = TestDataGenerator.createCase(con,'New');
            insert newCase ;
            newCase.status = 'Reopened';
            newCase.ownerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
            update newCase ;

            Case_Comment__c customCaseComment = TestDataGenerator.createCustomCaseComment(cs, 'New');          
            insert customCaseComment;

            Test.startTest();
            ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('id',cs.id);
            ApexPages.StandardController controller = new  ApexPages.StandardController(cs);
            EditpageOverridecontroller editPageOverride = new EditpageOverridecontroller(controller );

            editPageOverride.iscommunityuserflag = true;
            editPageOverride.method1();           
            editPageOverride.changestatus();
            editPageOverride.iscommunityuserflag = true;
            editPageOverride.TxtAr = 'Test Comment';
            editPageOverride.bol = true;        
            editPageOverride.changestatus();

            Test.stopTest();
        }
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
public class EditpageOverridecontroller{
public String caseid{get;set;}
//public pageReference pg{get;set;} 
public String TxtAr{get;set;}
public Boolean Bol{get;set;}
public boolean iscommunityuserflag{get;set;}

    public EditpageOverridecontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    }

    public pageReference method1(){    
   // String us = userinfo.getUserType();
   // system.debug(us);
   // if(us == 'High Volume Portal' || us == 'Customer Portal User' || us == 'Customer Portal Manager')
   // iscommunityuserflag = true;
        Id profileId=userinfo.getProfileId();
        String profileName=[Select Id,Name from Profile where Id=:profileId].Name;
        system.debug('ProfileName'+profileName);
        if(profileName == 'Customer Community Subscription Administrator')
            iscommunityuserflag = true;


        caseid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
        Case cs = [select status from case where id=:caseid];
        if( iscommunityuserflag == null ){
            system.debug('%%%%%%');    
           // PageReference pageRef1 = new PageReference('https://samltest--edb.cs13.my.salesforce.com/'+caseid+'/e?nooverride=1');
            PageReference pageRef1 = new PageReference('/'+caseid+'/e?retURL=/'+caseid+'&nooverride=1&');
            system.debug('Hello'+pageRef1);
            return pageRef1;
        }    
        else 
            if(cs.status != 'closed' && iscommunityuserflag == true){
                if(cs.status == 'Solution Suggested') 
                {
                    PageReference pageRef11 = new PageReference('/'+caseid+'/e?retURL=/'+caseid+'&nooverride=1');
                    return pageRef11;
                }
                else{   
                    PageReference pageRef11 = new PageReference('/'+'apex/CaseCCViewPage?id='+caseid+'&retURL=/'+cs.id+'&nooverride=1');
                    return pageRef11;
                }


            }
            else
            {
                system.debug('%%%%%%^^^^^');
                return null;
            }


    }

    public pageReference changestatus(){
    system.debug('yyy'+TxtAr);
    system.debug('xxxxyyy'+Bol);
    if(TxtAr != null && TxtAr.trim().length() > 0){
    Case_Comment__c post = new Case_Comment__c ();
    post.Case_Number__c = caseid;
    post.Action_Name__c = 'Closed';
    post.Comments__c= TxtAr;

    insert post;
    }
    if(Bol == true){
    Case cse = [select status from case where id=:caseid];
    cse.status = 'Reopened';
    update cse;

    }
    PageReference pageRef12 = new PageReference('/'+caseid);
    system.debug('Hello'+pageRef12);
    return pageRef12;
     }}
```

Apex Class :

```
public class TestDataGenerator{

    public static User createUser (string usrLastName,string usrAlias, string usrEmail, string usrUsername,string usrCommunityNickname, Profile ProfileId, string usrTimeZoneSidKey, string usrLocaleSidKey, string usrEmailEncodingKey,string usrLanguageLocaleKey) {
        User usr = new User ();       
        usr.LastName = usrLastName;
        usr.Alias = usrAlias;
        usr.Email = usrEmail;
        usr.Username = usrUsername;
        usr.CommunityNickname = usrCommunityNickname;
        usr.ProfileId  = ProfileId.Id ;
        usr.TimeZoneSidKey = usrTimeZoneSidKey;
        usr.LocaleSidKey = usrLocaleSidKey;
        usr.EmailEncodingKey = usrEmailEncodingKey;
        usr.LanguageLocaleKey = usrLanguageLocaleKey;
        return usr;
    } 



    public static Account createAccount(String accountName,String Commercial_Vs_Government, String stringSLA){
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = accountName;
        acc.SLA__c = stringSLA;
        acc.Google_External_Id__c = 'E-8469-2A32-C247-77CE';
        acc.Commercial_Vs_Government__c = Commercial_Vs_Government;
        // acc.Internal_Escalation_1_User__c = usr.id ;
        // acc.Internal_Escalation_2_User__c = usr.id;
        return acc;
    }  

    public static Account createNewAccount(String accountName,String Commercial_Vs_Government, String stringSLA, User usr){
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = accountName;
        acc.SLA__c = stringSLA;
        acc.Commercial_Vs_Government__c = Commercial_Vs_Government;
        acc.Internal_Escalation_1_User__c = usr.id ;
        acc.Internal_Escalation_2_User__c = usr.id;
        acc.Google_External_Id__c = 'E-8469-2A32-C247-77CE';
        return acc;
    }     

    public static Contact createContact (string contactLastName,Account acc,String email){
        Contact con = new contact();
        con.LastName = ContactLastName;
        con.AccountId = acc.Id;       
        return con;
    }

    public static User createNewUser (contact con, string usrLastName,string usrAlias, string usrEmail, string usrUsername,string usrCommunityNickname, Profile ProfileId, string usrTimeZoneSidKey, string usrLocaleSidKey, string usrEmailEncodingKey,string usrLanguageLocaleKey) {
        User usr = new User ();  
        usr.contactId = con.id;     
        usr.LastName = usrLastName;
        usr.Alias = usrAlias;
        usr.Email = usrEmail;
        usr.Username = usrUsername;
        usr.CommunityNickname = usrCommunityNickname;
        usr.ProfileId  = ProfileId.Id ;
        usr.TimeZoneSidKey = usrTimeZoneSidKey;
        usr.LocaleSidKey = usrLocaleSidKey;
        usr.EmailEncodingKey = usrEmailEncodingKey;
        usr.LanguageLocaleKey = usrLanguageLocaleKey;
        return usr;
    } 

    public static Contract createContract (Account acc, String ContractStatus){
        Contract contr = new Contract ();
        contr.AccountId = acc.id;
        contr.Status = ContractStatus;
        return contr;
    }

    public static Contract_Role__c createContractRole (Contract contr , Contact con, String ContractRole  ){
        Contract_Role__c conRole = new Contract_Role__c ();
        conRole.Contract__c = contr.id;
        conRole.Contact__c = con.id;
        conRole.Role__c =ContractRole ;
        return conRole;
    }

    public static Case createCase( Contact con, String caseStatus){
        Case cs = new Case();
        // cs.AccountId = acc.id;
        cs.ContactId = con.id;
        cs.Status = caseStatus;
        cs.Status = 'New';

        return cs;
    }

    public static Case createNewCase( Account acc,Contact con, String caseStatus){
        Case cs = new Case();
        cs.AccountId = acc.id;
        cs.ContactId = con.id;
        cs.Status = caseStatus;
        cs.Status = 'New';

        return cs;
    }
    public static CaseComment createCaseComment(Case cs, String caseCommentBody){
        CaseComment caseCom = new CaseComment ();
        caseCom.ParentId = cs.id;
        caseCom.CommentBody = caseCommentBody;
        return caseCom;
    }

    public static EmailMessage createEmailMessage(case cs){
        EmailMessage emailMsg = new EmailMessage ();
        emailMsg.ParentId = cs.id;
        emailMsg.MessageDate = DateTime.now();
        return emailMsg ;
    }

    public static Case_Escalation_Days__c createCaseEscalationDays (String escName, Integer day1, Integer day2){
        Case_Escalation_Days__c  caseEscDays = new Case_Escalation_Days__c ();
        caseEscDays.Name= escName;
        caseEscDays.Days_1__c = day1;
        caseEscDays.Days_2__c = day2;
        return caseEscDays;
    }


    public static Group createGroup (String grpName){
        Group grp = new Group();
        grp.Name = grpName;
        return grp;
    }

    public static Case_Comment__c createCustomCaseComment(Case cs , string actionName){
        Case_Comment__c customCaseComment = new Case_Comment__c ();
        customCaseComment.Case_Number__c = cs.id;
        customCaseComment.Action_Name__c = actionName;
        return customCaseComment ;
    }

    public static Internal_Case_Comment__c createInternalCaseComment(Case cs ,string actionName){
        Internal_Case_Comment__c internalCasecomment = new Internal_Case_Comment__c();
        internalCasecomment.Case__c = cs.id;
        internalCasecomment.Action_Name__c = actionName;
        return internalCaseComment;
    }

    public static Attachment createCaseCommentAttach (Case_Comment__c  customCaseComment){
        Attachment attach = new Attachment();
        attach.ParentId =customCaseComment.id;
        // attach.Body =  Blob.ValueOf('test case comment');
        return attach;
    }

    public static Attachment createInternalCaseCommentAttach(Internal_Case_Comment__c internalCasecomment ){
        Attachment attach = new Attachment();
        attach.ParentId = internalCasecomment.id;
        //attach.Body =  Blob.ValueOf('test internal case comment');
        return attach;
    }

    public static Promotions__c createPromotion (String promoName){
        promotions__c promo = new Promotions__c();
        promo.Name = promoName;
        //promo.Promotion_Detail__c = promoDetails;
        return promo;
    }

    public static Download__c createDownload(String downloadName, String downloadLink){
        Download__c download = new Download__c();
        download.Name = downloadName;
        download.download_Link__c = downloadLink;
        //download.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
        return download;
    }

    public static Download_Hit_Count__c createDownloadHitCount(Download__c download){
        Download_Hit_Count__c downloadHitCount = new Download_Hit_Count__c();
        downloadHitCount.Download__c = download.id;
        return downloadHitCount;
    }

    public static List<Account> createAccountUsingGoogleId(){
        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        for(Integer i=0; i<5; i++){
            accList.add(new Account(Name = 'Test Account '+i, Google_External_Id__c = 'E-8469-2A32-C247-77C'+i));
        }
        return accList;
    }
}
```

How can i increase the code coverage.Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest marking your TestDataGenerator with @isTest for an example of creating test data see the Trailhead module [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/apex_testing/apex_testing_data).
When you are testing your extension maybe try and think about how you would test it in the UI then replicate those steps in your test class. This should also include navigating to the page and simulating clicking buttons or calling methods. You should then also assert what you believe should happen when the different actions are performed. Take a look at the testing best practices docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods) for an example. Don't test just to cover lines of code, test to ensure your application is working as you expected.
Example from docs:

> ```
> public static testMethod void testMyController() {
>
>        //Use the PageReference Apex class to instantiate a page
>        PageReference pageRef = Page.success;
>
>        //In this case, the Visualforce page named 'success' is the starting point of this test method. 
>        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
>
>        //Instantiate and construct the controller class.   
>        thecontroller controller = new thecontroller();
>
>        //Example of calling an Action method. Same as calling any other Apex method. 
>        //Normally this is executed by a user clicking a button or a link from the Visualforce
>        //page, but in the test method, just test the action method the same as any 
>        //other method by calling it directly. 
>
>        //The .getURL will return the page url the Save() method returns.
>        String nextPage = controller.save().getUrl();
>
>        //Check that the save() method returns the proper URL.
>        System.assertEquals('/apex/failure?error=noParam', nextPage);
>
>        //Add parameters to page URL
>        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('qp', 'yyyy');
>
>        //Instantiate a new controller with all parameters in the page
>        controller = new thecontroller(); 
>
>        //Example of calling the 'setter' method for several properties. 
>        //Normally these setter methods are initiated by a user interacting with the Visualforce page, 
>        //but in a test method, just call the setter method directly. 
>        controller.setLastName('lastname');
>        controller.setFirstName('firstname');
>        controller.setCompany('acme');
>        controller.setEmail('firstlast@acme.com');
>        nextPage = controller.save().getUrl();
>
>        //Verify that the success page displays
>        System.assertEquals('/apex/success', nextPage);
>
>    }
> ```